# Apk Expansion files - resource not found

Tags: android, expansion

I have imported the sample app given by google in sdk.

I have around 60 images in my project, for testing purpose i have made a zip folder and renamed it as `main.2.com.abc.ss.obb.` so that i can use this .obb file for testing? Is this the right way to do it?

Now i have not uploaded the sample app given in the sdk in my console to test, before that i want to test it on device, is there any way i can test it?

When i just run the app it says "Downloading failed resource not found"

Comment: I am having a really hard time understanding your sentences. Could you please rewrite?

Comment: why downvoted? is it not the right question?

Comment: I downvoted because " in a that i have made a zip folder and renamed it as" is not correct grammar *and* I cannot understand it or the rest of the question. If you rewrite in a more understood way I will gladly take it back.

Comment: @yarian i have around 60 images now i need to create the obb file and test it before uploading the sample app in dev console? how to do it?

Comment: @yarian i have edited, have you worked on this, if so please help me

Comment: So you have a sample app and a zip folder that is an expansion to the APK and you want to test it? Try doing `adb push [path to obb file] Android/obb/<package-name>/` The Doc on expansion files has some info, have you looked there? http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25127/discussion-between-goofy-and-yarian)

Answer (score 3):

You can move the extension file manually to the device for example with `adb push`.

It has to go to the SD card in directory: `Android/obb/your.package.name/`. Assuming your package name is `com.abc.ss` a command similar to

```
adb push main.2.com.abc.ss.obb /sdcard/Android/obb/com.abc.ss/main.2.com.abc.ss.obb
```

will do the trick. The path to the sdcard may vary depending on device and android version.

Comment: hey, i am testing on real device, i have created folder like this Android.obb/com.abc.ss ... is this correct ? and how to create the .obb files?

Comment: Should be Android/obb/com.abc.ss

Comment: how to create the obb files? what ever i am doing is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is just a zip archive renamed to have an .obb extension.

Comment: but still why it is showing downlaoding failed, if the resource is avaiable then it should not downlaod right?

Comment: If it still tries to download, the checks for a correct download file in the app fail. Typically the app checks for the version number (`2` in your case) and for the file length in bytes. Make sure these checks pass correctly.

Comment: i am getting true here in this method expansionFilesDelivered(), even if i place the obb file or not place tha why so?

Comment: ok how to extract the images in that folder and display? sorry i am asking too many questions

Comment: You can get an `InputStream` of the image directly from the zip file (no need to extract the file). See for example `com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile.getInputStream(String)` from the play_apk_expansion library.